# Loading multiple project DLLs

Tags: excel, visual-c++, xll

Can someone please help me with this XLL load issue that I am facing?

I have a DLL solution, under which I have prj1 and prj2.

prj1 has prj1cppfile which has couple of user defined functions that I wrote.

prj2 has prj2cppfile which has some more user defined functions that I wrote.

Now, I select solution make prj1 as my start up project.

I then hit <kbd>F5</kbd> to start using my code in debug mode.

What I observe is (in the Excel spreadsheet that opens up) I have only functions from prj1cppfiles.

When I select prj2 as my startup project, I see the functions that I have in prj2cppfiles.

Now what I want is to have both the prj1 and prj2 to load so that i see functions from prj1cppfile and prj2cppfile which are sitting in two different projects.

Can someone please help me to solve this issue. I want to set up a solution in such a way that no matter what startup project I choose (prj1 or prj2) I should have be able to expose all the functions (from prj1cppfile and prj2cppfile) in excel.

I am using Visual Studio 2008 and I am using Keith Lewis code's XLL codes from Codeplex. I am new to writing XLLs, so please give me a detailed answer as I am trying to learn in the process.

---

what i observed is in the debug folder of the solution prj1.dll and prj2.dll exists. i choose prj1 as my start up project and hit f5 key to open up excel. i then go the the debug folder and drag and drop the prj2.dll in the excel that is open. when i do this i have access to all the functions are are in prj1.dll and prj2.dll. is it not possible to have a master dll which will contain all the functions that the different dlls hold ? what is a way to set up this master dll.

Best

Comment: How do you tell Excel to load the XLL? Is yout TargetDirectory the working directory for debugging? In that case you should copy the XLLs to a common directory and use this directory as the working directory while debugging.
BTW: Solutions are container for projects. A project can be a DLL project. There are no DLL Solutions.